# ROS publishing array from python node

Tags: python, arrays, ros

I'm new to ros+python and i'm trying to publish a 1-D array from python ros node. I used Int32MultiArray but i cant understand the concept of layout in multiarray. Can anyone explain it to me? or is there any other way of publishing an array ?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('test_drone')
import numpy
import rospy
import sys
import serial
from std_msgs.msg import String,Int32,Int32MultiArray,MultiArrayLayout,MultiArrayDimension
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats

#port = "dev/ttyS0"
#baud = 115200

#ser = serial.Serial()
#ser.port = port
#ser.baudrate = baud



################################################################################################


def main(args):
   pub=rospy.Publisher('sonar_vals',Int32MultiArray,queue_size = 10)
   rospy.init_node('ca_serial')
   r = rospy.Rate(0.2)
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      print "LOOP running"
      a = [3250,2682,6832,2296,8865,7796,6955,8236]
      pub.publish(a)
      r.sleep();



     # try:
         #data_raw = ser.readline()
     # except e:
        # print e
      #sd = data_raw.split(',')   
      #a = numpy.array([sd[0],sd[1],sd[2],sd[3],sd[4],sd[5],sd[6],sd[7],sd[8],sd[9]],dtype=numpy.float32)
      #if sd[0] == 777:
      #   pub.publish(a)
     # else:
       #  print 'Invalid Data'




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, getopt
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*MultiArray` messages are a bit overkill in your case. I think it is much simpler if you create your own simple message type `IntList` for this (see [this tutorial on how to create custom messages](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)). The `IntList.msg`-file looks just like follows:

```
int32[] data
```

To publish a list with this message use the following snippet:

```
a = IntList()
a.data = [3250,2682,6832,2296,8865,7796,6955,8236]
pub.publish(a)
```

Note that you cannot directly publish the list but have to instantiate an `IntList` object and fill the `data` member of this object (this holds for all message types, even if you just want to publish a single integer!).

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to use `MultiArray`, try:

```
array = []
my_array_for_publishing = Int32MultiArray(data=array)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following methods for python:

```py
pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter2', Float64MultiArray, queue_size=10)
data_to_send = Float64MultiArray()  # the data to be sent, initialise the array
data_to_send.data = array # assign the array with the value you want to send
pub.publish(data_to_send)
```

Answer (score 0):

MultiArray* messages are discouraged for custom applications (use custom messages instead). For quick prototyping and using generic data visualization tools they seem to be OK (see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/325559/how-can-we-actually-use-float32multiarray-to-publish-2d-array-using-python/) for a discussion). In ROS2 you can use this to quickly test sending

```
publisher = node.create_publisher(Float32MultiArray,'topic',10)
data = [0.0, 1.0]
publisher.publish(Float32MultiArray(data=data))
```

And this to unpack the message on the other side. Messages are already array objects there.

```
subscription = node.create_subscription(
        Float32MultiArray,'topic',listener_callback,10)
...
def listener_callback(msg):
    rclpy.logging.get_logger().info('I heard: %f %f' % (msg.data[0], msg.data[1]))
```